# ^0* Regular Expression is not working java

Tags: java

Hello I am new in Regular Expression

```
^0* - 
g
^ asserts position at start of the string
0* matches the character 0 literally (case sensitive)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

for String  "3454tdfgffg" it should return false, as there is no zero

below is my example

```
public class RegExTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
          String pattern ="^0*";

          String instance = "3454tdfgffg";

          // Create a Pattern object
          Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

          // Now create matcher object.
          Matcher m = r.matcher(instance);
          if (m.find()) {
              System.out.println("Available");
          }else
          {
              System.out.println("Not available");
          }

    }
}
```

but it is always returning true, what ever i write in instance variable

can you please solve me, where i am wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will always return true.

`0*` matches the character `0` repeated between **zero** and **unlimited** times. In your string, this character is missing, so it means that the character `0` is **repeated zero times** and the match returns `true` as expected.

If you need to match at least one zero, use `^0+`

Comment: Don't know why such people downvote, I have already return that I have not much knowledge

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit I think it's because it is written in your question too: `* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)`. Anyway, regex can be difficult if you are new to them, so I'm glad the answer helped :)

Comment: why not sure :)